# Xcode NSRangeException on second run through of code

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uitableview

Now I know what an NSRangeException is. What I dont get is why on the first run through of my code it's fine, but when the same code (and variables) are setup the second time it fails. Even stepping through the code I can't see where it is differing from the first run through.

The whole code gets a set of JSON values from my php api (basically just client information, units booked in, date, etc.) It used to just display it in a UITableView, I decided to group my table by the date it was booked in (Apple should have a nicer way to do this in my opinion, perhaps extending their UITableView?)

my .h

```
    @interface LTBViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;

NSArray *tickets;  //for storing our serialized JSON
NSMutableData *data; //for appending our JSON as we're getting it
NSString *token; //for security authentication with our custom API


NSMutableArray *days; //for storing any days with bookings retrieved from tickets
NSMutableDictionary *groupedTickets; //for storing tickets to correlate to days
NSArray *filteredArray; //for our finalized output
}
@end
```

most of my .m (the important parts)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/api/api.php?api=%@&function=%@", token, @"active"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];



    //[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; old way of doing it
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //initialize from our settings file and make sure we're authenticated
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    token = [defaults objectForKey:@"api_token"];
    NSLog(@"%@",token);

    //initialize our sorting arrays
    days = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    groupedTickets = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    filteredArray = [[NSArray  alloc] init];
}


- (void)groupTable {


    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (LTBViewController *ticket in tickets)
    {

        NSString *date = [[tickets objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"dateIn"];
        if (![days containsObject:date])
        {
            [days addObject:date];
            [groupedTickets setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:ticket] forKey:date];
        }
        else
        {
            [((NSMutableArray*)[groupedTickets objectForKey:date]) addObject:ticket];
        }
        count +=1;

    }
    count = 0;
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}


//for when we get a response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


//for getting data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)thedata
{
    [data appendData:(thedata)];

}


//for when connection finished
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    tickets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NO error:nil];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [self groupTable]; //starts our grouping methods
}


//for when connection fails
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Could not connect to server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorView show];
}

//overriding the "delete" text for our UITableView
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return @"Close Ticket";
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *date = [days objectAtIndex:section];
    return date;
}


- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [days count];
}


- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *date = [days objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
    return [[groupedTickets objectForKey:date] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0; //rounds our table corners

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle) reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

//I'm sure theres a better way to do this but it works for now

    NSString *date = [days objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    NSPredicate *search = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateIn == %@", date];

    filteredArray = [tickets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:search];
```

//this right here is what fails the second time through at index 1

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[filteredArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"ticketnumber"] ]; 

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"customerName"]];

    return cell;
}
```

When an item is clicked it moves to another view controller (that works alright) but when the back button is pressed from it is where this code fails. I would be appreciative of any extra sets of eyes going over it and helping me find my error. (or a better way of doing this)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I thought when I reassigned values to my NSMutableArray days and NSMutableDictionary groupedTickets it would just overwrite the previous values.

I performed release on view will disappear and it works now.

Still if there's a better way to do this I'd be interested in learning it.